# How to assign first JLabel background color to the next JLabel since mouse events are void?

Tags: java, swing, colors, mouseevent, jlabel

Right now, I'm working on another `JPanel` with 9 `JLabel` each assigned with a different `Color`. What the application is to do is when the user clicks on the first panel, nothing happens except that the color of the `JLabel` will be registered to an instance variable and when he/she clicks on a second `JLabel`, the color of this second one will have to change to the first one previously. And this suppose to go on when the third one is clicked, color registered and will change the fourth one to the third's color.

So my question is since the `MouseListener` events are all void methods, how am I going to achieve that result? Is there a way to bypass the void methods? Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

class TilePanelB extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    JLabel label1;
    JLabel label2;
    JLabel label3;
    JLabel label4;
    JLabel label5;
    JLabel label6;
    JLabel label7;
    JLabel label8;
    JLabel label9;

    JLabel theLabel;
    JLabel theLabelB;

    Color temp;
    Color tempB;

    public TilePanelB() 
    {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        Dimension labelSize = new Dimension(300, 300);

        label1 = new JLabel();
        label2 = new JLabel();
        label3 = new JLabel();
        label4 = new JLabel();
        label5 = new JLabel();
        label6 = new JLabel();
        label7 = new JLabel();
        label8 = new JLabel();
        label9 = new JLabel();

        label1.setPreferredSize(labelSize);
        label2.setPreferredSize(labelSize);
        label3.setPreferredSize(labelSize);
        label4.setPreferredSize(labelSize);
        label5.setPreferredSize(labelSize);
        label6.setPreferredSize(labelSize);
        label7.setPreferredSize(labelSize);
        label8.setPreferredSize(labelSize);
        label9.setPreferredSize(labelSize);

        label1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        label2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        label3.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        label5.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        label6.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        label7.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        label8.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        label9.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        label1.setOpaque(true);
        label2.setOpaque(true);
        label3.setOpaque(true);
        label4.setOpaque(true);
        label5.setOpaque(true);
        label6.setOpaque(true);
        label7.setOpaque(true);
        label8.setOpaque(true);
        label9.setOpaque(true);

        this.add(label1);
        this.add(label2);
        this.add(label3);
        this.add(label4);
        this.add(label5);
        this.add(label6);
        this.add(label7);
        this.add(label8);
        this.add(label9);

        label1.addMouseListener(this);
        label2.addMouseListener(this);
        label3.addMouseListener(this);
        label4.addMouseListener(this);
        label5.addMouseListener(this);
        label6.addMouseListener(this);
        label7.addMouseListener(this);
        label8.addMouseListener(this);
        label9.addMouseListener(this);  
    } // end of constructor

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        theLabel = (JLabel)e.getSource();       //First click from the user
        temp = theLabel.getBackground();        //Stores the background color of JLabel

        theLabelB = (JLabel)e.getSource();      //Second click from the user

        if(!theLabelB.getBackground().equals(theLabel.getBackground()))
        {
            tempB = theLabel.setBackground(temp);   //Assigns background color of next JLabel to temp variable
        }
    }
    // end of constructor

}   // end of class
```

Comment: This could be better done with `JButton` objects with colored icons and an `ActionListner` to detect mouse clicks.

Comment: @AndrewThompson oh hey hi Andrew! ok sure noted. but it's a past school work kind of tutorial so I just follow the document lol.

Answer (score 2):

void has nothing to do with this. You simply change the state of your class with each button press. Give your class variables for the color of the JLabel pressed, and then change the state of these variables from within the mouse listener.

i.e.,

```
private Color lastColorPressed = null;

// in mousePressed:
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
  Color thisColor = label.getBackground();
  if (lastColorPressed != null) {
    label.setBackground(lastColorPressed);
  }
  lastColorPressed = thisColor;
}
```

Side note 1: I usually avoid overriding the mousePressed method in favor of the mouseClicked method, since mouseClicked will still work if you move the mouse between click and release.

Side note 2: regarding your code:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    theLabel = (JLabel)e.getSource();       //First click from the user
    temp = theLabel.getBackground();        //Stores the background color of JLabel

    theLabelB = (JLabel)e.getSource();      //Second click from the user
    //....
```

How does theLabelB represent the second click while theLabel represents the first click? That doesn't make sense to me as the source can not possibly change in the less than millisecond time between both calls to `e.getSource()`. Please understand that both variables **must** refer to the very same object.

Comment: Hi Sir thanks so much for your help again! May I ask you how does **lastColorPressed** play its part? I'm getting confused again lol. :) Cheers!

Comment: @Scorpiorian83: it simply stores the last color obtained. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Hi Sir can I ask you another question? I managed to understand your code but one thing is i'm taught that our code are so-called processed or read from top to bottom. So how come `lastColorPressed = thisColor;` will still get processed and return to the if statement for processing? Thanks! :)